# Django DB transactions and deadlocks

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python, django-orm

When running Django with Gunicorn with multiple processes/workers I'm getting a deadlock issue with some of my manual MySQL database transactions.

```
DatabaseError(1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction')
```

My setup uses multiple databases, and my function needs to be passed the database to use when it's called. For this reason, I can't use the standard [Django transaction decorators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/transactions/) as the db needs to be hard-coded as an argument. I've inspected the decorator code to look at how transactions are managed, and my function looks like this:

```
from django.db import connections

def process(self, db, data):

    # Takeover transaction management
    connections[db].enter_transaction_management(True)
    connections[db].managed(True)

    # Process
    try:
        # do things with my_objects...
        for obj in my_objects:
            obj.save(using=db)
        connections[db].commit()
    except Exception as e:
        connections[db].rollback()
    finally:
        connections[db].leave_transaction_management()
```

Can anyone spot what may be going wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

Note you might want to use the more clear `with`-style syntax. The following should be identical to your code above, but more pytonic.

```
from django.db import transaction
from __future__ import with_statement

def process(self, db, data):

    with transaction.commit_on_success(using=db):
        # do things with my_objects...
        for obj in my_objects:
            obj.save(using=db)
```

or with a decorator

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.commit_on_success(using=db)
def process(self, db, data):    

    # do things with my_objects...
    for obj in my_objects:
        obj.save(using=db)
```

That does not solve your deadlock problem though..

You might have success with lowering your transaction isolation level. This defaults on mysql to `REPEATABLE READ` wich is too strict for most usages. (oracle defaults to `READ COMMITTED`')

You can achieve this by adding this to your `settings.py`

```
MYSQL_DATABASE_OPTIONS = {'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB; SET 
                 SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;'}

DATABASES = {
  'default': {  # repeat for each db
       'ENGINE':  ... etc
       ...
       ...
       'OPTIONS': MYSQL_DATABASE_OPTIONS
      }
  }
```