# Changing MySQL isolation level on Django/Elastic beanstalk/RDS

Tags: python, mysql, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to change the isolation level of my MySQL instance on RDS through a Django application.
I've followed the recommendation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213481/django-db-transactions-and-deadlocks)

So, I changed my Django db settings to:

```py
'OPTIONS': {
    'init_command': 'SET default_storage_engine=INNODB; SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED'
}
```

This command works fine when I run directly in the database (MySQL version 8.0.13)
However, when I try to deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk I got the following error:

```
Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)... manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED' at line 1")
```

I also tried changing the line to:

```
SET default_storage_engine=INNODB, SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
```

With the same results

Any idea what might be wrong? Or another solution that I can use (maybe I can just run this command and set it to global isolation level instead?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps that `OPTIONS` cannot handle 2 commands.  So remove the first one -- it is useful only when creating a new table.  And it may be possible to specify the `ENGINE=InnoDB` on any `CREATE TABLEs` you need to do.  Anyway, I would expect AWS to default to that.  And 8.0 has that engine default.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try like below, anyone should work.

```
SET @@SESSION.transaction_isolation = value;
SET SESSION transaction_isolation = value;
SET transaction_isolation = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

For **MySQL**, you will be able to set and check `READ COMMITTED` by running the raw queries after **database settings** in `settings.py` as shown below. *If running the raw query before **database settings**, error occurs:

```py
# "settings.py"

from django.db import connection

# ...

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'DB_USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

# ↓ ↓ ↓ Set isolation level ↓ ↓ ↓

cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """
        SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
        """
cursor.execute(query)

# ↓ ↓ ↓ Check isolation level ↓ ↓ ↓

cursor.execute('SELECT @@GLOBAL.transaction_isolation;')
print(cursor.fetchone()) # ('read committed',)
```

*`settings.py` is run every time **Django Server** is run with the command below or every time **Django Server** is reloaded by writing code so transaction is set every time **Django Server** is run with the command below or every time **Django Server** is reloaded by writing code:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

For me with **PostgreSQL**, `"init_command": ...` and `"isolation_level"` in `"OPTIONS": {}` below didn't work so I couldn't set `SERIALIZABLE` in `settings.py`:

```py
# "settings.py"

"OPTIONS": {
    "init_command": "ALTER DATABASE postgres SET DEFAULT_TRANSACTION_ISOLATION TO 'SERIALIZABLE';"
    "isolation_level": psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_SERIALIZABLE,
}
```